# Newline delimited output for Saxon-HE 9.6 from command line

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

Is there any way to get newline delimited output on multiple matching nodes for Saxon-HE 9.6 ?

I use this wrapper named `saxon-lint` :

```
#!/bin/bash

java -cp /path/to/saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -s:"$2" -qs:"$1" !method=text
```

Example :

#### file.xml

```
<house_pet_hazards>
  <hazard type="cleanup">
    <name>hairballs</name>
    <guilty_party species="cat">Dilly</guilty_party>
    <guilty_party species="cat">Nameless</guilty_party>
    <guilty_party species="cat">Katie</guilty_party>
  </hazard>
</house_pet_hazards>
```

#### COMMAND LINE :

```
$ saxon-lint '/house_pet_hazards/hazard/guilty_party' file.xml
```

#### OUTPUT :

```
DillyNamelessKatie
```

#### EXPECTED OUTPUT :

```
Dilly
Nameless
Katie
```

---

#### EDIT

[I've found a semi-working solution by searching google hardly](http://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/mailman/message/20634561/) proposed by [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay), so I wrote this wrapper :

```
#!/bin/bash

xpath="$1"
[[ -s $2 ]] && file="$(readlink -f "$2")" || file=/dev/stdin

java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:"for \$x in doc('file://$file')$xpath
return (data(\$x),text{'&#10;'})" !method=text
```

#### output :

```
$ saxon-lint "/house_pet_hazards/hazard/guilty_party" /tmp/file.xml
Dilly
Nameless
Katie
```

But the problem I found is that when I use the path

```
house_pet_hazards/hazard/guilty_party
```

I get error

```
Error on line 1 column 37 
  XPST0003 XQuery syntax error near #...p/file.xml')house_pet_hazards/#:
    expected "return", found name "house_pet_hazards"
Static error(s) in query
```

or

```
./house_pet_hazards/hazard/guilty_party
```

I get error :

```
Error on line 1 column 37 
  XPST0003 XQuery syntax error near #... doc('file:///tmp/file.xml')./#:
    expected "return", found "."
Static error(s) in query
```

---

#### [The wrapper](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint)

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query selects three element nodes; the effect of the text output method is to construct a document node containing these three elements, and then output the string value of the document node, which is the concatenation of the string values of the three elements.

In principle you can solve the problem by setting the item-separator serialization attribute to a newline. Unfortunately I can't find any way to achieve this on the command line, since newline terminates the command. Perhaps !item-separator="\n" will work in some shells, but when I try it you get a literal "\n" as the item separator.

So I think you have to change the query to insert the separators explicitly, using string-join().

Comment: Thanks Michael Kay. Is there some known problems with Mac Os X to use `!key=value` ? Tested OK for both Cygwin and Linux. I published my wrapper on github : https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint/blob/master/saxon-lint

Comment: In some Unix-like shells (I don't know exactly which), "!" needs to be escaped as "\!".

Comment: I tried this, but it's more a behaviour in interactive shells AFAIK (like bash). Anyway, my Mac Os X if from 2006 so I have to test with a fresh Os X. As far as I use [tag:bash], the use of `$'\n'` as a separator seems portable and work well for Linux/Cygwin.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just change your query string to:

```
-qs:"string-join(/house_pet_hazards/hazard/guilty_party,'&#xA;')"
```

You could also shorten the path to `//guilty_party` as well.

Example bash script in Cygwin:

```
[/cygdrive/c/apps/SaxonHE9-6-0-3J]
==> cat saxon-lint.bsh
#!/bin/bash.exe

java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -s:$2 -qs:"string-join($1,'&#xA;')" !method=text

[/cygdrive/c/apps/SaxonHE9-6-0-3J]
==> ./saxon-lint.bsh //guilty_party so.xml
Dilly
Nameless
Katie
```

Comment: Yeah you're using count() in your query string which returns an integer. That can't be the first arg of string-join(). Maybe you should move string-join out of the bash and use it on the command line. Make the query string in the bash just -qs:"$1"

Answer (score 0):

On bash, you can add this as a serialization parameter:

```
 $'!item-separator=\n'
```

This uses bash `$''` syntax which enables some escape characters such as `\n`.

Mind you, it won't print a newline after the last item.